# Trying to mimic the Apple iPad popover style

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

My sincere apologies if this question has been asked, but I really couldn't find it.

Essentially, I am trying to mimic the look of the popovers used by the built-in Apple applications.  In particular, not the popovers that use a tableview list, but rather those popovers that only have buttons inside.

For example, in the Mail app, clicking the left-facing arrow on the top right of the screen, a popover is shown with four buttons: Reply, Reply All, Forward, Print.

How is this particular popup created to give that look?

I have tried making my own UIViewController with a black background and Round Rect Buttons, but it doesn't look the same.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `UIActionSheet`. On iPad, it gets a "popover" appearance if it's not presented from within another popover.

Comment: Oh, so I don't actually use UIPopoverController in this instance?  I just create an UIActionSheet that is IBAction-ed from a button, like on the iPhone?

Comment: Yes, you can present it from a `UIBarButtonItem` or from a rectangle and it'll appear as a popover.